# Node.js to pick up images from S3. But some folders work and some do not

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

We use Node.js to pick up images from S3. Images from some folders can be picked up perfectly, but some failed to be picked up.

We use quite consistent way to name the directory and images themselves. For example, our website is a property website. Each property has one folder with name ABC-001, ABC-002... ABC is the source of the property, and we currently have 5 sources. 001 is the number of property under each source. Under each folder (XXX-###), images are named as ABC-001_001, ABC-001_002...

The problem is we can pick up for example, images from ABC-001 folder, but fail to do so from ABC-002 folder. Does anyone have any suggestions why this is happening?

For more information, we have 142 folders for the moment. It seems the failure starts to happen from 131st folder. Is this a coincidence? We have also tried to delete all folders and reupload, make public, refresh again.

Really appreciate you help in advance!

Comment: We figured it out. It is due to 1000 object limit within one bucket.